# Mechanize select from dropdown

Tags: python, mechanize

I want to mechanize to check if the current value of selected dropdown = the default value, then mechanize will choose another value in the list instead.
The html of the dropdown is as follow:

```
            <td class="label">List</td>
            <td>
                <select name="list" id="list" onchange="list()">
                    <option>---</option>
                 <option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
---other options---
```

My code is:

```
if br.form["list"] == "---":
    br.form["list"].value = "1"
    r = br.form["list"]
    print(r)
```

However list value still returns:

```
   ['---']
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the value as a list:

```
if br.form["list"] == ["---"]:
    br.form["list"].value = ["1"]
```

According to the [`mechanize` - Forms documentation](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html):

> ```
> # Controls that represent lists (checkbox, select and radio lists) are
> # ListControl instances.  Their values are sequences of list item names.
> # They come in two flavours: single- and multiple-selection:
> form["favorite_cheese"] = ["brie"]  # single
> form["cheeses"] = ["parmesan", "leicester", "cheddar"]  # multi
> ```