# Handle webpages that change using python and mechanize

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to automate some actions on a website using python and mechanize. I can login, navigate to a form, populate the form, then submit. However, mechanize is having a hard time finding the "form" I'm trying to submit.

**Edit**
When I do

```
br.open(url)
print br.response().read()
```

It has the `<form>` tag there... but when I do

```
for form in br.forms():
    print form
```

I get this error...
[image]

Instead of the above, since the "form" in question does not have a name attribute and is the only form on the page, I do

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

and I get the same error message. Any ideas?

**Edit**
Here is the html from `br.reponse().read()`

[image]

I saw somewhere to wrap it in BeautifulSoup then spit it back out using make_response method...

[image]

but I still get the same error..

Comment: Select the drop down and then click the button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934003/mechanize-select-from-dropdown :)

Comment: Actually it looks like the drop down is just toggling visibility. And the text and dropdown fields are all there in the code. The problem I'm having is that mechanize is not seeing the form tag.

Comment: It might help if you share the HTML as well. At least the relevant portion.